# Unity Preview from a specific blend tree animation to another animation

Tags: unity, animator

I have a blend tree that switches from `Idle` to `Walk` to `Run` animations via the `run` parameter (0 to 1).

[image]

In the preview I would like to see how works the transition between the `Walk` (or `Run` animation) and `Jump` animation, but the blend tree always stays on the `Idle` animation even if the `run` parameter is set to 1.

There is a solution ? or do I necessarily have to see it in playmode?

Thanks

[image]